# Why can we use global variable in browser?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babel-loader

As we know, the global variable is `window` in browser and `global` in nodejs.

I read source code about some NPM package, their use `global` like `global.Set` instead of `window.Set`. When I import that package, it works well in my project base on browser. It confuse me.

I think the reason is `babel`. Maybe use `global` can write cross-platform package by `babel`? But how it works.

[package use global](https://github.com/jankapunkt/js-set-extension/blob/master/package/lib/index.js)

Comment: I would suggest to add the package name and example of what you are doing.

Comment: one could do `window.global = window` and then, et voila, `global.Set` will work (I would hope that's NOT how it is being done though)

Comment: At least in the future we will have `globalThis`,.. for this exact reason.

Comment: @Art3mix Thank, I have add it.

Comment: @Keith I know the `globalThis`. I just confused about `global`. Maybe `babel` or `core.js` work? I cant figure out it. I have a test using `babel-loader` to transform `.js` file including `console.log(global)`. And it can print the object that is `window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in babel nor webpack, far from it, but looking at the output code from webpack, you can see that webpack is injecting the `global` variant to your code if you use it, so if we have a simple code like:

```
console.log("just a test");
```

This is what ends up in our source code:

```
eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n/* harmony default export */ __webpack_exports__[\"default\"] =
```

But, if we would use the next code:

```
console.log("just a test", global);
```

This is our output:

```
eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\n/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(global) {//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n/* harmony default export */ __webpack_exports__[\"default\"] =
```

You can clearly see the change.

Found this [issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/6227) that you might find helpful in figuring this out.

From what I understood babel is using [this](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/internals/global.js) internally, so it exports it if you use it in the code.

Please note that you can't access `global` variant in the console.

**Note**
`global` and `window` are the same object, it is not a copy, so all changes done to `global`, will be done on `window`

Comment: I create an [minimum test](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-wzcmqj). It use typescript but also can print `global`, Amazing.

Comment: I think this is something that stackblitz adds, because global is `undefined` in chrome and firefox, and I tried it [here](https://codepen.io/Art3mix/pen/VwZVwJy) as well with a bable processor, still global is `undefined`.

Comment: Also important note, this is not the global that is on your nodejs, this is a simple rename like in the previous answer below `let global = window`

Comment: Thank you. I create an [minimum project](https://github.com/Eracal/global/tree/master) again and push it to Github. Can be run by `npm install && npm run start`. There are just a simple `console.log(global)` and transform by `babel-loader`.

Comment: Sorry for reply delayed. Because of some problem in sf, I can't comment or other action:(
 I have question to the author. `For creating the dist we use babel 7 and it should create ECMA5 compatible code`

Answer (score 0):

To always use the keyword `global`:

```js
if (!(typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports)) global = window;

console.log( global.name )
```

Comment: how would you use global.Set like the question actually asks :p